# Best practice how to evaluate a list of Maybes

Tags: haskell, monads

i am looking for a function which takes a function (a -> a -> a) and a list of [Maybe a] and returns Maybe a. Hoogle gave me nothing useful. This looks like a pretty common pattern, so i am asking if there is a best practice for this case?

```
>>> f (+) [Just 3, Just 3]
Just 6
>>> f (+) [Just 3, Just 3, Nothing]
Nothing
```

Thanks in advance, Chris

Comment: I don't know, that's why i am asking.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to match your updated question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should first turn the `[Maybe a]` into a `Maybe [a]` with all the `Just` elements (yielding `Nothing` if any of them are `Nothing`).
This can be done using [sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:sequence), using Maybe's Monad instance:

```
GHCi> sequence [Just 1, Just 2]
Just [1,2]
GHCi> sequence [Just 1, Just 2, Nothing]
Nothing
```

The [definition of sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Monad.html#sequence) is equivalent to the following:

```
sequence [] = return []
sequence (m:ms) = do
  x <- m
  xs <- sequence ms
  return (x:xs)
```

So we can expand the latter example as:

```
do x <- Just 1
   xs <- do
       y <- Just 2
       ys <- do
           z <- Nothing
           zs <- return []
           return (z:zs)
       return (y:ys)
   return (x:xs)
```

Using the [do-notation expression of the monad laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws), we can rewrite this as follows:

```
do x <- Just 1
   y <- Just 2
   z <- Nothing
   return [x, y, z]
```

If you know how the Maybe monad works, you should now understand how `sequence` works to achieve the desired behaviour. :)

You can then compose this with `foldr` using `(<$>)` (from [Control.Applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--36--62-); equivalently, `fmap` or `liftM`) to fold your binary function over the list:

```
GHCi> foldl' (+) 0 <$> sequence [Just 1, Just 2]
Just 3
```

Of course, you can use any fold you want, such as `foldr`, `foldl1` etc.

As an extra, if you want the result to be `Nothing` when the list is empty, and thus be able to omit the zero value of the fold without worrying about errors on empty lists, then you can use this fold function:

```
mfoldl1' :: (MonadPlus m) => (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> m a
mfoldl1' _ [] = mzero
mfoldl1' f (x:xs) = return $ foldl' f x xs
```

and similarly for `foldr`, `foldl`, etc. You'll need to import [Control.Monad](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html) for this.

However, this has to be used slightly differently:

```
GHCi> mfoldl1' (+) =<< sequence [Just 1, Just 2]
Just 3
```

or

```
GHCi> sequence [Just 1, Just 2] >>= mfoldl1' (+)
Just 3
```

This is because, unlike the other folds, the result type looks like `m a` instead of `a`; it's a *bind* rather than a *map*.

Answer (score 14):

As I understand it, you want to get the sum of a bunch of maybes or `Nothing` if any of them are `Nothing`. This is actually pretty simple:

```
maybeSum = foldl1 (liftM2 (+))
```

You can generalize this to something like:

```
f :: Monad m => (a -> a -> a) -> [m a] -> m a
f = foldl1 . liftM2
```

When used with the `Maybe` monad, `f` works exactly the way you want.

If you care about empty lists, you can use this version:

```
f :: MonadPlus m => (a -> a -> a) -> [m a] -> m a
f _ []      = mzero
f fn (x:xs) = foldl (liftM2 fn) x xs
```

Comment: Nice solution, although I prefer mine since it can easily be used for non-folds too. However, yours is simpler if the only use is folding.

Comment: On the other hand there's something cute about 1 followed by 2. But maybe cuteness isn't the best metric of code quality...

Comment: Unfortunately, I have a feeling that the desired behaviour might be to return `Nothing` when the list is empty, in which case the fun juxtaposition is lost :(

Comment: (Although I don't think your solution is actually able to handle that behaviour at all, unfortunately.)

Comment: Is there any good way to handle empty lists without making the code specific to `Maybe`?

Comment: Yes: `mzero` from MonadPlus, `empty` from Alternative or `mempty` from Monoid (in order of preference, IMO; MonadPlus is just an older duplicate of Alternative that depends on Monad instead of Applicative, but Monad doesn't require Applicative yet, so it avoids adding an additional constraint, and Monoid doesn't have the right kind to work well here).

Comment: `mzero` sounds like a nice option.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise your solution could be adapted to use mzero too. However, I'd suggest you inline the definition of `foldl1` in the fallback case, since right now it needlessly uses a partial function, even though you know the list isn't `[]`.

Comment: Erm, what exactly do you mean by "inline the definition of `foldl1`"?

Comment: Turning `f fn l = foldl1 (liftM2 fn) l` into `f fn (x:xs) = foldl (liftM2 fn) x xs` per the definition of `foldl1`; it's no big deal, just avoids calling a partial function when you don't need to.

Comment: Ah, I see. I guess that makes sense.

Comment: Returning `Nothing` for empty lists seems counterintuitive to me, I  would prefer `foldl` and zero element because otherwise it will mix two different cases in one. BTW, another variation is `foldl1 (liftA2 (+)) [Just 1, Just 10, Just 100]`

Comment: @VictorMoroz: That's certainly an option. On the other hand, I don't think returning `Nothing` is particularly unintuitive, and `f` in the question did not have any starting value.

Answer (score 6):

What about something as simple as:

```
λ Prelude > fmap sum . sequence $ [Just 1, Just 2]
Just 3
λ Prelude > fmap sum . sequence $ [Just 1, Just 2, Nothing]
Nothing
```

Or, by using `(+)`:

```
λ Prelude > fmap (foldr (+) 0) . sequence $ [Just 1, Just 2]
Just 3
λ Prelude > fmap (foldr (+) 0) . sequence $ [Just 1, Just 2, Nothing]
Nothing
```

So, `maybeSum = fmap sum . sequence`.

Comment: Just noticed that ehird answer already contains this version! When reading ehird's reply, as soon as I saw the word `MonadPlus`, I though: "There must be an easier way" and I didn't bother continuing: Sorry! Anyway, I've upvoted ehird's answer.

Comment: Haha, no big deal :) Good point about `MonadPlus`, I've attempted to make it clearer. (Accidentally deleted my previous comment by holding down a key, oops...)